How to implement page break on react-draft-wysiwyg editor?
I am trying to implement the page break as soon as the content goes beyond the parent div.
I have tried two ways,
first by creating a list of <Editor> components as soon as the editor element height is greater than the parent div height.. and then appending a new <Editor> , but on further typing the created Editor i.e. the second editor state is not getting updated.
second,  inserts a block of type page-break into the editor as soon

but I'm unable to add any text beyond the page break block ..
I can't find any supporting docs for page break implementation.
How can I implement it?
